# cfsavecontent not saving to excel

Tags: excel, coldfusion

I get data from the query. But it is not saving in the EXCEL file.  Any suggestions?

When I do the cfdump on the query results.  Data is coming through. It seems that data is not being saved at all.

```
 <cfif ListQuery.RecordCount gt "0">

     <!--- <cfoutput query="NewDataset"> (<-From an include file)--->
     <!--- <cfdump var="#NewDataset#"> --->

     <cfsavecontent variable="PriceList">
         <cfoutput query="ListQuery">
             #VarA#,#VarB#,#VarC#
         </cfoutput>
     </cfsavecontent>
     <cffile file="E:\PriceLists\#FileName#" action="APPEND" output="#Trim(PriceList)#">

</cfif>
```

Comment: What do you mean "not saving in the EXCEL file"? CFSavecontent just saves text to a variable. It has nothing to do with Excel. (Edit) That said, are you getting an error? Perhaps it is because the above code only creates the `#PriceList#` variable IF the query contains one or more records. So your `cffile` statement should be placed inside the `CFIF` block.

Comment: Please review again... Seems like some of my text didnt show up.

Comment: Dump of query results - you mean <cfdump var="#listQuery#"> right? I'm not seeing that - not even in the commented out dump (which is dumping #newdataset#. Where is this dump taking place? is it BEFORE your <cfif> Is anything showing up in the file (line breaks maybe?).

Comment: So what are the results of the new code? It is difficult to tell without more info or an error message. BTW, I would start with some basic troubleshooting. Print data to the screen at each step 1) Dump the `ListQuery` query *before* the cfif block, otherwise you may not see it 2) *Inside* the cfif, dump `#PriceList#` to view what should be appended to the file 3) Add a `cfelse` clause. Display a message if the query is empty.

Comment: cffile action="append" only works with text files to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to append to a CSV. What happens when you try to open it in Notepad?

Comment: http://www.raymondcamden.com/2011/6/1/ColdFusion-Sample--Create-an-Excel-File

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sample code... It may solve this..

```
<cfif ListQuery.RecordCount gt "0">
    <cfsavecontent variable="PriceList">
        <cfloop query="ListQuery">
            #VarA#,#VarB#,#VarC# //Here your result, what you need to show in excel
        </cfloop>
    </cfsavecontent>

    <cfcontent type="application/msexcel;charset=windows-1252" reset="yes">
    <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="filename=PriceLists.xls">
        <cfoutput> #PriceList# </cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

I hope this example solve your problem.